# Called object is not a function or function pointer `int v = (userInput >= 'a' && userInput <= 'z') (userInput >= 'A' && userInput <= 'Z')`

Tags: c

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char userInput;
    printf("Enter a letter:  "); 
    scanf("%c", &userInput);

    int vowelVerification = (userInput == 'a'  userInput == 'e'  userInput == 'i'  userInput == 'o'  userInput == 'u' userInput == 'A'  userInput == 'E'  userInput == 'I'  userInput == 'O'  userInput == 'U');
    // Checks if the userInput is a vowel.

    int consonantVerification = (userInput >= 'a' && userInput <= 'z')  (userInput >= 'A' && userInput <= 'Z');
    // Checks if the userInput exists in the alphabet.


    if (vowelVerification) {
        //  The UserInput is a vowel.
        printf("VOWEL!"); 
    }
    else if (consonantVerification) {
        // The UserInput is a consonant.
        printf("CONSONANT!");
    }
    else {
        // The UserInput is neither a consonant nor a vowel.
        printf("INVALID INPUT!");
    }
}
```

It always says "called object is not a function or function pointer
int consonantVerification = (userInput >= 'a' && userInput <= 'z') (userInput >= 'A' && userInput <= 'Z').

Comment: A title of "Does anyone know what's wrong with this code?" is not useful. That applies to pretty much every question on this site.

Comment: There is a `||` missing in the line mentioned in the error message.

Comment: What do you expect `(userInput >= 'a' && userInput <= 'z') (userInput >= 'A' && userInput <= 'Z')` to do?  Did you forget an operator between the sets of parenthesis?

Comment: Also, multiple `||` missing in the initialization of vowelVerification.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you're missing a `||` operator. The reason you get this specific error message is the parser is looking at "*expression* ( *other expression* )" and expecting a function call. So it assumes *expression* is either a function or a function pointer.